# Copy specific file when it exists with Ansible

Tags: ansible, copy

I have a role where I need a standard file for most cases, but a specific one for some hosts.
In the `file` folder of my role, I have `file.default` and `file.{{ ansible_hostname }}` for specific cases.

Is there a nice way to do this in one task ?
Or do I have to do it in three (stat if the specific file exists, copy it if yes, copy standard if not) ?

Thank you

Comment: Are the differences between the files small enough that it could be a template? If so, you could use a (or multiple) variable(s) with a default in that is overridden for those specific hosts in `hosts_vars`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/first_found.html) !

```
- name: |
        copy first existing file found to /some/file,
        looking in relative directories from where the task is defined and
        including any play objects that contain it
  copy: src={{lookup('first_found', findme)}} dest=/some/file
  vars:
    findme:
      - foo
      - "{{inventory_hostname}}"
      - bar
```